# Change CLASS for every index in array

Tags: php, css, foreach

Suppose I have an array with different and repeated values like
**['zaid','zaid','ali','khan','khan','zaid','jhone','jhone']**

What I want,

I want to display every repeated value with the same BG-COLOR with the same pattern.

like:

```
<span style="background-color:#ddd">ZAID</span>
<span style="background-color:#ddd">ZAID</span>
<span style="background-color:#E55">ALI</span>
<span style="background-color:#099">Khan</span>
<span style="background-color:#099">Khan</span>
<span style="background-color:#ddd">ZAID</span>
<span style="background-color:#055">JHONE</span>
<span style="background-color:#055">JHONE</span>
```

I am doing like this now you batter understand what I want.

**$row['who_first_check']** is an string with comma separated values.

```
$checkerNames   =   explode(",",$row['who_first_check']);
$i              =   0;
$a              =   'a';
foreach($checkerNames as $cnName){
    echo '<span class="userCheck" style="background:#'.$a++.$i++.'2; border:1px solid #'.$a++.$i++.'2;">'.$cnName.'</span>';
}
```

Comment: The name of the item in the array denotes the colour.

Comment: I want to assign a color. To every repeated value.

Comment: Why downvote the question? If you don't understand then ask me I will explain more as I can.

Comment: You have to store the color that is connected to the array value so you can use it again if you encounter that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably want to use an associative array. Like so:

```
$names = array('zaid' => 'eee', 'khan' => 'ccc');
foreach($names as $key => $item){
  echo "<span class='element-name--$key'>$key</span>";
}
```

Now I'll guess that you have another file that generates a CSS style sheet (or you can do it as inline styles in the same page if you wish). And in here you can do this:

```
foreach($names as $key => $item){
  echo ".element-name--$key {background-color: #$item}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an associative array like below

```
$arr=array("zaid"=>"#ddd","ali"=>"#E55","jhone"=>"#055","khan"=>"#bb099b");
//loop your repeated array
$input=['zaid','zaid','ali','khan','khan','zaid','jhone','jhone'];
foreach($input as $val){
  $colour=$arr[$val];
  echo "<span style='background-color:".$colour."'>".$val."</span>";

}
```

Comment: Thanks so I should assign a color to every index first.

Comment: Yes, it is better to make separate array rather than assigning to  repeated values

Comment: I update my question can you please look into it now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your array, and for each element, decide upon which colour to use:

```
<?php

$items = array('zaid','zaid','ali','khan','khan','zaid','jhone','jhone'); 

foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item == 'zaid') {
      $colour = '#ddd';
    }
    else if ($item == 'ali') {
      $colour = '#E55';
    }
    else if ($item == 'khan') {
      $colour = '#099';
    }
    else if ($item == 'jhone') {
      $colour = '#055';
    }
    echo `<span style="background-color:$colour">$item</span>`;
}

?>
```

The use of the PHP variables inside of the `echo` allow you to set up different outputs while staying within the loop.

Note that the above is a bit sloppy (as it could use a `switch` statement instead), but will get the job done.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It's not a dynamic solution. what if the array values will be changed?

Comment: You need some way to associate the values to the desired colours. Without such a definition, checking each element is the only option.

Comment: Then help me out with that thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array1 = Array('zaid','zaid','ali','khan','khan','zaid','jhone','jhone'); 
foreach($array1 as $array) 
{ 
  echo "<span class='$array'>$array</span>"; 
 } 
?>
```

css

```
<style>
.zaid
{
    background-color:#ddd;
}
.ali
{
    background-color:#E55;
}
.khan
{
 background-color:#099;
}
.jhone
{
background-color:#055;
}


</style>
```

Comment: You have errors... I think you mean `<?php

$array1 = Array('zaid','zaid','ali','khan','khan','zaid','jhone','jhone');

foreach($array1 as $array)
  {
    echo "<span class='$array'>$array</span>";
  }   

?>    
`

Comment: I think I should pass style in a loop as well.